# How can i save xml file in sqlite database...?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am writing a project where I am required to save an entire XML file in a database. So how can I save it? I don't want to save parsed XML only the entire XML file.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Have you managed to save anything to the database yet? Please post some code or give more information

Comment: Ya i have saved the xml into to byte array in blob field but when i retrieve it giving the unapropriate data

Answer (score 5):

The content of an XML file is a text. So use a column of type text and insert the whole content of the file.

Comment: Ok but this may limit to the field size.

Comment: "The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000)." (http://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length)

Comment: Ok i got it, Thank you for helping Hyperboreus.